# Dictionary like data structure in Arduino C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, arduino

I am writing a USB to PS/2 converter in Arduino and I have a data structure that I would implement like a dictionary if I were using another higher level language. The entries would be something like:

```
{ 0x29: { name: "esc", make: [0x76], break: [0xfe, 0x76] } }
```

Here, 0x29 is the USB code for the key, so that's the key for this dictionary lookup. Then, I would use `entry.name` for debugging purposes, `entry.make` is the array of bytes I need to send when the key is pressed (keyDown) and `entry.break` when the key is released (keyUp).

What would be a a way to achieve this in C++?

Comment: How about a bunch of enums and switch cases?

Comment: `std::map<unsigned int, MyStructure>`?

Comment: on @rustyx's note: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=87778.0 , also maybe https://arduinojson.org/ (although it feels like the overhead will be bigger than std::map) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [ArduinoSTL 1.1.0](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl) doesn't include `unordered_map` so you could create a `map` like this.

1. Download the Arduino STL ZIP file and put it somewhere good
2. Sketch\Include Library\Add ZIP library and give it the full path to the ZIP file.

Then this should compile, albeit with a lot of STL warnings about unused variables.

```
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct key_entry {
    std::string name;
    std::string down;
    std::string up;
    key_entry() : name(), down(), up() {}
    key_entry(const std::string& n, const std::string& d, const std::string& u) :
        name(n),
        down(d),
        up(u)
    {}
};

using keydict = std::map<unsigned int, key_entry>;

keydict kd = {
    {0x28, {"KEY_ENTER",  "\x5a", "\xf0\x5a"}},
    {0x29, {"KEY_ESC",    "\x76", "\xf0\x76"}}
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin( 115200 );  
}

void loop() {
    auto& a = kd[0x29];
    // use a.down or a.up (or a.name for debugging)
    Serial.write(a.up.c_str(), a.up.size());
}
```

Comment: I am getting multiple compiling errors: https://gist.github.com/fcoury/cab3fbc3a8fdc40f109475e5320b36de

Comment: I have the sketch here if you want: https://create.arduino.cc/editor/fcoury/483d1d94-afd1-4b31-85d2-7658cc2daf12/preview

Comment: I'll see if I can get my arduino-environment up. Haven't started it in years and have never used the STL in it myself. Will be interesting :-)

Comment: That is really appreciated. i am updating the Gist with new attempts I'm making. Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it! Check this new gist:https://gist.github.com/fcoury/623d3d0ce9be0dddba80779172b9e51e

Comment: Looking good! I changed my answer to use `std::string` and also added how I think you should be able to do `Serial.write(buf, len);`.

Comment: That's great! I just realized that the initialization I proposed is a bit clumsy so I just edited it to show a simpler way (although I don't know if the numbers I put in there are correct or not).

Comment: Looks great and yes, this looks cleaner as well. Thanks!